# Shortcuts for finding geometrical isomers

Tags: stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

Our teacher provides us extra questions for pratice, so one of the questions was :-

> Find number of products if following are reacted with excess $\ce{NH2OH}$ (hydroxyl amine):
>
> Cyclohex - 
> (i) 1,4-dione 
> (ii) 1,3-dione 
> (iii) 1,2-dione 
> (iv) 1,2,3 trione 
> (v) 1,2,4-trione 
> (vi) 1,3,5-trione  and 
> (vii) cyclobut-1,2,3,4-tetraone

To solve this, our teacher told us replace each $\ce{=O}$ group by 1 $\ce{-CH3}$ and 1 $\ce{-H}$ , then find the number of stereoisomers (including enantiomers) of the resultant compound, which is the answer.(if you actually count it's tough to visualize the lone pair and $\ce{-OH}$ bond and it gets long).

I have cross-checked , the answers pretty much match. So my doubt is, is this trick always right and if yes then please prove it. I would also be content if you can provide any links, if the question has already been answered.

---

I had another doubt, about another trick my teacher told us about. Let's say there's a compound with $n$ carbon atoms forming a closed ring of all $n$ carbons. At each carbon, out of 2 $\ce{-H}$ , 1 $\ce{-H}$ is replaced by $\ce{-Cl}$ (chlorine). The trick if $n$ is odd ,the number of geometrical isomers of the compound is $2^{(\frac{n-1}{2})}$ and if $n$ is even then the number of geometrical isomers is $2^{(\frac{n}{2})}$. Please prove this also.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the last sentence starting by "The trick is", the word "odd" has to be replaced by "even"

Comment: @SirArthur7 You have the Suggested Edits queue red and full with your enthusiasm! Go on by all means(our site is getting better!), but I would urge you to make more complete edits. Deal with all problems in the same suggestion, don't just handle formatting/markdown and leave out grammar.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamR.Ebenezer currently on another edit. Could I come back later?

Comment: I am pretty much sorry for that, actually when you have to delve into such huge articles and you're rushing with time, you might miss out on a few things. But I will try to look after that from now on, thanks for the suggestion. Happy to be of help :)